# bootstrap modal with table row

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a HTML table on my page as shown below where rows are populated by `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="sermon in sermons | filter:searchText">
    <td align="center">{{ sermon.sermondate }}</td>
    <td>
        <b>{{ sermon.sermontitle }}</b>
        <p>{{ sermon.sermonsummary }}</p>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <a ng-href="" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-sermontitle="{{ sermon.sermontitle }}" data-sermonlink="{{ sermon. sermonlink }}">
    <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <td align="center" class="download"><i class="fa fa-download fa-2x"></i></td>
```

My jquery code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) { 
        console.log('button clicked.');
        // Button that triggered the modal
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 

        // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var sermontitle = button.data('sermontitle') 
        var sermonlink = button.data('sermonlink')

        // Update the modal's content.
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-title').text(sermontitle)
        modal.find('iframe').attr('src',sermonlink);
    });
});
```

And here is my HTML for modal

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Youtube video should play here.</p>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dmBWI5EZyHM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I wanted to achieve is when a user clicks on the youtube link in a table row, a modal will show up with the youtube link passed in data-attribute.

After spending whole my day researching this I am still not successful to do it.

Here is my sample sermon JSON

---

```
[ { "id" : "1",
    "sermondate" : "2015-09-27",
    "sermonlength" : "39",
    "sermonlink" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Za4jjt80kLw",
    "sermonsummary" : "A must watch.",
    "sermontitle" : "Sunday Morning Service Sep 27 2015",
    "sessionid" : "1",
    "viewcount" : "46"
  },
  { "id" : "2",
    "sermondate" : "2015-10-11",
    "sermonlength" : "54",
    "sermonlink" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXj8nY0oOF8",
    "sermonsummary" : "This sermon deals with the important issues of Christian walk.",
    "sermontitle" : "Bible Study 11th October",
    "sessionid" : "3",
    "viewcount" : "16"
  },
  { "id" : "4",
    "sermondate" : "2015-10-11",
    "sermonlength" : "41",
    "sermonlink" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91xBFt3de1s",
    "sermonsummary" : "This sermon was preached by pastor James Sipes in Sunday Morning church service on 11th October 2015.",
    "sermontitle" : "Sunday Morning Service Oct 11 2015",
    "sessionid" : "1",
    "viewcount" : "13"
  },
  { "id" : "5",
    "sermondate" : "2015-10-18",
    "sermonlength" : "17",
    "sermonlink" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jnEoBChZ9I",
    "sermonsummary" : "This sermon was preached by Kurt Robertson in Sunday school service on 18th October 2015.",
    "sermontitle" : "Missionary to North Korea - Oct 18 2015",
    "sessionid" : "1",
    "viewcount" : "18"
  },
  { "id" : "6",
    "sermondate" : "2015-10-18",
    "sermonlength" : "46",
    "sermonlink" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRf8X7Zgt8c",
    "sermonsummary" : "This sermon was preached by Kurt Robertson in Sunday Mornign church service on 18th October 2015.",
    "sermontitle" : "Sunday Morning Service Oct 18 2015",
    "sessionid" : "1",
    "viewcount" : "6"
  },
  { "id" : "7",
    "sermondate" : "2015-11-01",
    "sermonlength" : "50",
    "sermonlink" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnF8EARhTwA",
    "sermonsummary" : "This sermon was preached by Pastor JAmes Sipes in Sunday school service on 1st November 2015.",
    "sermontitle" : "Bible Study Nov 01 2015",
    "sessionid" : "1",
    "viewcount" : "5"
  }
]
```

Comment: Just in case, HTML code example has an unintentional space in `sermon. sermonlink`.

Comment: thanks Anrejs....i saw that later on. Thanks for pointing that out though such silly mistakes sometimes cost days...

Answer (score 0):

Go the other way around - use `click` on the button / link itself :

```
$('a[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function() {
    $(".modal-title").text($(this).attr('data-sermontitle'));
    $("#player").attr('src', $(this).attr('data-sermonlink')+'?autoplay=1');
})
```

Here setting `autoplay` too, only difference is that I have given the `<iframe>` an `id`, `player`, but that is not necessary.

Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/32u97dau/**

I did not make a plnkr / angular-demo since we do not have an example of `sermons` and cannot replicate `"sermon in sermons | filter:searchText"` - but this is not important, the above will work in your project too.

---

**Some explanation**
`$(document).ready()` is simply useless in a angular context. `ready()` is executed when the document has finished loading, but at that time angular has just started up and not finished its *digest* or rendering business. So it would never work if you rely on things should be "ready" in the DOM, i.e. the table is rendered by `ng-repeat`.  A dirty "hack" is to use a `$timeout` instead :

```
$timeout(function() {
  //what you do in $(document).ready()
})
```

To the contrary `$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]',...` works because it is a [**delegated event handler**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). It means you attach the handler to the parent `document` but it is executed for the child selector `a[data-toggle="modal"]` - it works on injected / added markup, thus it works for you too in angular.

In the future, try avoid using jQuery - or at least jQuery as you are using it now. You have [**angular ui bootstrap**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and [**angular strap**](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) (which I prefer) wrapping bootstrap the Angular way. You can use $timeout as a ready substitute and use ng-click instead of attached jQuery event handlers.

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything wrong with my angular routeConfig. My modal is contained within the "sermons.html" which is served by routeconfig thru angular. 

When I use your solution on a standalone page it works fine but it still doesnt work when my actual semons.html is served by angular routeconfig.

Comment: I added sample JSON at the bottom of question

Comment: One more thing I noticed I put console.log stmnt in click event jquery and it never showed up in console...!!! So I kept a log stmnt immediately after $(document).ready function and that shows up on console..!!

Comment: Finally I got it resolved but with a strange finding. When I use `$(document).ready` it does not work. But when I use `$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {....` it works. What is the difference??? Would like to know if any one can help me understand ..

Comment: @SherebyahTishbi, OK - was about to produce an angular example now I've got the JSON, but have added some explanation to the answer to your question in the comment above instead.

Comment: `@davidkonrad` that's good details of jQuery intricacies. Thanks for the `ng-click` suggestion, that totally makes sense.